# ASP.NET Core call Google API to get Contacts or Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

My goal is simple: login to Google and be able to retrieve the contacts, email or call any other Google API.

Log in is simple using the ASP.NET Core Authentication library:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
        options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
    }
);
```

After a lot of searching, the only examples I see is using the Google API for C#. Is there any way to call the Google API only using the ASP.NET Core libraries? Or do I've to use the Google libraries?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a start you can go though the google contacts api but i recommend you try going though the people api instead as it should give you the same results and its a newer api.

I didnt have time to test this but let me know if its not working i will help you get it working

## startup.cs

```
public class Client
    {
        public class Web
        {
            public string client_id { get; set; }
            public string client_secret { get; set; }
        }

        public Web web { get; set; }
    }



    public class ClientInfo
    {
        public Client Client { get; set;  }

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ClientInfo(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            Client = Load();
        }

        private Client Load()
        {
            var filePath = _configuration["TEST_WEB_CLIENT_SECRET_FILENAME"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"Please set the TEST_WEB_CLIENT_SECRET_FILENAME environment variable before running tests.");
            }

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"Please set the TEST_WEB_CLIENT_SECRET_FILENAME environment variable before running tests.");
            }

            var x = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Client>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ClientInfo>();

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
                {
                    // This is for challenges to go directly to the Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
                    // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
                    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    // This is for forbids to go directly to the Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
                    // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
                    o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    var clientInfo = new ClientInfo(Configuration);
                    options.ClientId = clientInfo.Client.web.client_id;
                    options.ClientSecret = clientInfo.Client.web.client_secret;
                });
            services.AddMvc();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
```

## Controller with Auth

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ContactsController : ControllerBase
{
    
    private readonly ILogger<ContactsController> _logger;

    public ContactsController(ILogger<ContactsController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // Test showing use of incremental auth.
    // This attribute states that the listed scope(s) must be authorized in the handler.
    [GoogleScopedAuthorize(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly)]
    public async Task<GetReportsResponse> Get([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth, [FromServices] ClientInfo clientInfo)
    {
        
        var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
        var service = new  PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = cred
        });                       

        // Make the request.
        var response = service.People.Get().Execute();
        return response;
    }
}
```